# Setting Oracle client identifier

Tags: .net, oracle, visual-studio-2015

How to set oracle session client Id for audit purposes using sql datasource control on update or delete in .net web application vs2015

example for hard coded connection

```
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand

    cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.CommandText = "dbms_session.set_identifier('machine_name')"

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.close()
```

how can i do this on sqldatasource control or even on the application level

Comment: Please be more specific. Given an example of what you're trying to accomplish, what code you've tried, and what kind of errors you're getting.

Comment: I’m using sql datasource  control for a dev express gridview I need for every delete or update to save the client user in oracle client Identifier in every connection session for audit